# The expression "that more of a ..."

Tags: expressions

I was surfing on the web when I read the following sentence :

"Many TV shows today use animation and animation gives them **that more of a** unique look, allowing them to do more than what they could do with actors."

The expression "that more of a" seems unusual to me although I understand the sense.

Is that sentence correct?

Comment: The sloppy prose: "That more of a unique look," should probably read: *a distinctive look*.

Comment: Perhaps "**more of that** unique look"?  This gets around the "grading of uniqueness", which I, among many others here, disdain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"them that more of a"

is an unfortunate reduction from this core which is shown at Google Books (not vanilla Google):

["them that **much** more of a"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22that%20more%20of%20a%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22them%20that%20much%20more%20of%20a%22)

Now,

*"gives them **that much more of** a unique look"*

roughly means:

*"gives them **even more of** a unique look"*

or:

*"gives them **something that is much more of** a unique look"*

or, simplified:

*"gives them **a very** unique look"*

Comment: 'A very unique look' is certainly pushing it. Unique is an absolute adjective.  'That much more of a unique look' sounds more acceptable, as a paraphrase of 'a more nearly unique look'.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Surely, anything added to "unique" is a no-no in classical/classicist terms:-)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  The sentence quoted is a most tortuous piece of text, and would barely be acceptable from an eleven-year-old. The grading of *unique* is the least of its sins, in my view. Like me you probably got told at school that something was either unique or not unique. But it does tend to be a gradable adjective these days.

Comment: @Marius Hancu 'Almost unique' is fine.

Comment: @WS2 Have you eaten a descriptivist tablet? Yes, ODO has 'Words like unique have a core sense but they often also have a secondary, less precise sense: in this case, the meaning ‘very remarkable or unusual’, as in a really unique opportunity. In its secondary sense, unique does not relate to an absolute concept, and so the use of submodifying adverbs is grammatically acceptable.' But this usage rapidly becomes ambiguous and not contextually resolvable (his presentation was unique). I'll never use it, though I'm aware others might. But they're committing or at least encouraging ambiguity.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm not familiar with the term *descriptivist*. Is it the opposite of *proscriptivist*?

Comment: Prescriptivist (although they don't need to be disjoint). You are usually the first to protest when the old values seem about to disappear. I think this is one worth making a minor stand for. _The uniqueness of 'unique'_. Sounds good. We've already got words meaning 'remarkable' and 'unusual'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Quite so. Apologies for the typo. My children would regard me as a *proscriptivist* too; especially when it comes to things like junk mail, and cold calling residential phone numbers.

Comment: I aint buyin' your *reduction* chili :-) It reads like extemporaneous speech with  a "pause and redirect" at *that*, giving the *more of* expression **more of** a colloquial *closer to* meaning. It doesn't work well with *unique* regardless, but I can imagine the writer's thought in that pause: *It's not really **unique**, because everyone is doing it.* So *more of* serves to back away from the absurd absolute description the writer wants to offer. Some [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animation#cite_ref-Thomas_4-0) articles are just that bad.

Comment: I've got your back on this one, @EdwinAshworth. Words have meaning, so what's the point of ignoring the meaning? *Unique*: Being the **only one** of its kind; unlike anything else: some qualifications are counterproductive next to *unique*!

Comment: @ScotM I usually accept the inevitable populist moves in English, but I've got a traditionalist bone or two left.